# How to duplicate all records in a table SQL Server for n times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any SQL query to duplicate all records in a table for n times?
So lets say I have 1000 record in table1, Is there any SQL query to duplicate these 1000 record for n times? Instead of copy and pasting the data from the beginning?

Comment: `insert into t select * from t` will double the rows. One more time, and you've got 4 times the original no of rows.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` to a (inline) tally table's `TOP (@N)` rows?

Comment: @jarlh I do thank you but it gives me this error then "An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: @Larnu sorry I did not understand your point

Comment: What part, @Hassan ? `CROSS JOIN` or tally?

Comment: `insert into t (c2, c3, ...) select c2, c3, ... from t`, i.e. select all columns _except_ the identity column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jarlh and Larnu have given the solution in the request comments, but you are having difficulties understanding the concept.

The duplicates you are talking about are not real duplicates obviously. They differ in their IDs. This means you must list the columns and omit the ID: `insert into t (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from t`.

With an ad-hoc tally table:

```
insert into t (col1, col2)
  select col1, col2
  from t
  cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) tally(i);
```

Comment: That's right, both answers are correct and worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: Though, in truth, I would recommend against the `WHILE`, @Hassan ; it'll be *significantly* slower.

Comment: @Larnu yes larnu, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 10)
BEGIN
    --Do insert here
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```